# How to Use Batch File - Simple Application to Restart Audio Drivers

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, drivers, batch

I want a batch file to open CMD and run "net stop audiosrv", then "net start audiosrv", then kill CMD. I am having problems with a bunch of things including

- It's not waiting
- It is opening a new CMD
- It's not closing

Here is the code I wrote myself. I've never done any coding before and got this from what I did now/combining it with other things I've seen on here.

```
start cmd.exe /k "net stop audiosrv"

wait 10

start cmd.exe /k "net start audiosrv"    

TASKKILL /IM cmd.exe
```

I don't really think it matters but I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 - 64 bit

Comment: Your question is missing lots of detail. how are you executing the command? Via command line or a .bat file or some other means?

Comment: Hey thanks @Dave! I didn't know you could do it via just bat without opening cmd. I ending up removing the "start cmd.exe" portion, and then since I didn't open a cmd I could remove the TASKILL part, leaving me with a working:

`net stop audiosrv

wait 10

net start audiosrv
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems fine but it looks like you're sending this command at a time.

Save it to a bat file and execute it from there, you'll probably see it works fine (although you will need to not include things like the `start cmd.exe` obviously)!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Credit to [@Dave](https://superuser.com/users/146314/dave)

```
net stop audiosrv
net start audiosrv
```